# Magento 2 How to upgrade existing custom customer address attribute?

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, setup-upgrade

I have created a module, which creates one custom customer address attribute.
In my attribute I have visible true, Now I need to visible false.
I need to update that attribute. 
My code is as below:

```
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerSetup->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'custom_id', [
           'is_visible'  =>  false,
       ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'custom_id')
        ->setData([
            'used_in_forms' => [],
        ]);

       $attribute->save();
       $setup->endSetup();
}
```

**it's giving error "Unique constraint violation".**
How could I update this attribute

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did one mistake, removed from code and its working. Answer as below:

```
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerSetup->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'custom_id', [
           'is_visible'  =>  false,
       ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'custom_id');

       $attribute->save();
       $setup->endSetup();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see the method `updateAttribute` requires the field and the value, which should be string-type:

```
/**
 * Update Attribute data and Attribute additional data
 *
 * @param int|string $entityTypeId
 * @param int|string $id
 * @param string|array $field
 * @param mixed $value
 * @param int $sortOrder
 * @return $this
 */
public function updateAttribute($entityTypeId, $id, $field, $value = null, $sortOrder = null)
{
    $this->_updateAttribute($entityTypeId, $id, $field, $value, $sortOrder);
    $this->_updateAttributeAdditionalData($entityTypeId, $id, $field, $value);
    return $this;
}
```

So you should write a code like this:

```
$customerSetup->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'custom_id', 'is_visible', false);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Siarhey your answer is appreciated.